# Draw System Model using Latex TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw the following figure using TikZ. or at least using App that could provide Latex text interpretation. 
[image]
up to my knowledge, we can add figures (eg. servers and data query users) using TikZ as:

```
\def\QueryUser#1;{\draw #1 node {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{image}};}
```

If you could help or advice me.

Many thanks

Comment: Wow, it is a very nice image.

Comment: You can certainly draw such pictures with Ti*k*Z and I am not sure if your command will help you with that. Rather, you might want to write a minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and shows what you have tried. And while the cylinders and rectangle are pre-defined shapes, there is a question how you are going to get the remaining icons. Are you going to include some external graphics?

Comment: Yes, I want to add the servers and query users as figures using command mentioned in the question. I have tried to draw it but I struggled with bringing them at the appropriate positions.